# How many Clusters of Node.js app could be initialised per core?

Tags: node.js

I had googled about how many clusters could be initialized per core, and all articles I read sad that one node per core is good enough. Therefore, I haven't found a nice explanation about that.

I have an app that uses a lot of i/o and only does few computations, like push/remove from a queue then schedule a task to the database. For this app, I had initialized 5 clusters per core, and it had increased the number of requests I could receive. however the load Avg in the server is very high, about 30 sometimes.

The points are, what are the side effects using this approach (more than one node per core)?

Comment: What do you mean with "5 clusters per core"? The rule of thumb is one worker process per core (so if your have 4 cores, you start 4 worker processes).

Comment: i mean 5 worker process per core. i think you got the point, "the role of thumb", but why? I have started 20 workers process in a machine with 4 cores.

Comment: Are you using async I/O for all I/O that is anywhere other than server startup?  Or do you have some synchronous I/O sprinkled into your code/

Comment: everything is async.

Answer (score 0):

A single core can only run one process at a time.

Most processes that run on your computer are mostly idle (they sit around and wait for something to happen), that's how you can have dozens, or hundreds, of processes running on your computer without much problems.

However, *active* processes, that do a lot of stuff (like your processes do; and in this case, a lot of I/O also counts), keep a CPU core pretty busy. So it's useless to start more than one of such processes per core, because they will all be contending for a time slice on that core.

That's also why you get a high load average, which is an indication of how many processes are either *using* the CPU, or are *waiting* to use the CPU.